# How to connect to Oracle 11g using Oracle-SQL-Developer from a Mac

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, connectivity, oracle-sql-developer

I am currently running Oracle 11g on my Windows 10 machine, but I use my mac a lot and I want to connect to the installed Oracle 11g on my windows from my mac using  SQLDeveloper. How can you achieve that? I have made a few attempt using videos on youtube and following a few documentation on Oracle website without any success.

Comment: Are these machine on the same network? Lets say your mac is 192.168.1.10 and the Oracle Server is 1.11,  make sure both machine are able to ping each other. Then install SQL Developer on your mac machine and follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-0DE0C9F4-8800-4142-A755-14B2FAA6624F.htm#ADMQS12420) guide. On the hostname provide the IP address of the server.

Comment: Yes they are often on the same network but I also want to be able to connect when I'm not on the same network

Comment: @christianx if you're not on the same network you'll need a VPN of some sort to connect to the servers network-subnet. Did it work while being on the same local network?

Comment: What errors do you get when trying to connect? I can guess a lot of reasons .....